# JavaScript - capture img tags src in variable

Tags: javascript, html, css

im trying to store an image in HTML that comes from a url source in a variable using JavaScript. Could someone show me what code is required? i have started it off...

```
 var productImage = document.getElementById("productImg").//??;


<img id="productImg"
                    src="https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/1735db1c-d84f-417a-b871-27b63ee2b2e6_1.9a18f15c0e0fa321d0c5d073875b9738.jpeg?odnWidth=undefined&odnHeight=undefined&odnBg=ffffff" >
```

Comment: document.getElementById("productImg").src ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use the `src` property.

```
 var productImage = document.getElementById("productImg").src
```

You can also use the `src` property to set a new URL for the image if you want to replace it.

```
 var productImage = document.getElementById("productImg");
     productImage.src = URL
```

Comment: Great, i captured the src using .src as you suggested. I am now trying to output this as an image on another page. How would i append an img tag to add this url thats stored in local memory? thanks

Comment: If it's a page reload you would have to use localStorage or a cookie

Answer (score 0):

You were close. To obtain the value of an HTML element's attribute, you can access that attribute as a property of the DOM element.

```js
var productImage = document.getElementById("productImg").src;

console.log(productImage);
```

```html
<img id="productImg"
                    src="https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/1735db1c-d84f-417a-b871-27b63ee2b2e6_1.9a18f15c0e0fa321d0c5d073875b9738.jpeg?odnWidth=undefined&odnHeight=undefined&odnBg=ffffff" >
```